# how to add array element values with javascript?

Tags: javascript

I am NOT talking about concatenating elements together, but adding their values to another separate variable.

Like this:

```js
var TOTAL = 0;
for (i=0; i<myArray.length; i++) {
    TOTAL += myArray[i];
}
```

With this code, `TOTAL` doesn't add mathematically element values together, but it concatenates them next to each other, so if `myArray[0] = "10"` and `myArray[1] = "10"` then `TOTAL` will be `"01010"` instead of `20`.

How should I write what I want?

Thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Sounds like your array elements are Strings, try to convert them to Number when adding:

```
var total = 0;
for (var i=0; i<10; i++){
  total += +myArray[i];
}
```

Note that I use the unary plus operator (`+myArray[i]`), this is one common way to make sure you are adding up numbers, not concatenating strings.

Answer (score 3):

```
const myArray = [2, 4, 3];
const total = myArray.reduce(function(a,b){ return +a + +b; });
```

Answer (score 2):

A quick way is to use the unary plus operator to make them numeric:

```
var TOTAL = 0;
for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++)
{
    TOTAL += +myArray[i];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Make sure your array contains numbers and not string values. You can convert strings to numbers using parseInt(number, base)

```
var total = 0;
for(i=0; i<myArray.length; i++){
  var number = parseInt(myArray[i], 10);
  total += number;
}
```

Comment: It's not wise to leave off the radix parameter

Comment: Dammit, your absolutly right, was just to eager to get my answer out there. added it.

Comment: Really? Why isn't it wise? In Java it defaults to 10. Is it different in javascript?

Comment: @abyx, if you don't use the radix argument. it will depend on the string, '0xFF' will be parsed to 255, '010' to 8, and so on...

Answer (score 0):

Use `parseInt` or `parseFloat` (for floating point)

```
var total = 0;
for (i=0; i<10; i++)
 total+=parseInt(myArray[i]);
```