# Why isn't the sum of my array being returned on the click event?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I'm working on a project where the user adds numbers to an array and then, on a click event, the sum of those values is returned. However, the "total" button only ever returns 0 for my "total" variable. Just can't figure out the prob I set up the total variable based on what I saw here: [how to add array element values with javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1799184/how-to-add-array-element-values-with-javascript)

```
var times = [];

var total = 0;
for (var i = 0; i < times.length; i++) {
    total += +times[i];
}

document.getElementById("add").onclick = function () {
    times.push(1);
};

document.getElementById("total").onclick = function () {
    alert(times + " adds up to " + total);
};
```

Here's my [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/6sp29efd/)

Comment: Because you've computed the `total` **before** you pushed `1` to `times`???

Answer (score 1):

You need to put the code that calculates the total in the `total` `onclick` function.

```
document.getElementById("startsequence").onclick = function () {
    total = 0;
    for (var i = 0; i < times.length; i++) {
        total += +times[i];
    }
    alert(times + " adds up to " + total);
};
```

New jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/6sp29efd/3/

Comment: You need to reset the `total` to 0 in the handler, otherwise the next computation will add up to the previous result

Answer (score 1):

JavaScript (in the browser) runs sequentially. When the browser comes across this block of code:

```
for (var i = 0; i < times.length; i++) {
    total += +times[i];
}
```

it runs immediately. Your click handler, `document.getElementById("total").onclick` needs to recalculate the total every time it's clicked. I suggest using a function to do so:

```js
var times = [];

var getTotal = function (arr) {
    return arr.reduce(function (currentSum, next) { return currentSum + next });
}

document.getElementById("add").onclick = function () {
    times.push(1);
};

document.getElementById("startsequence").onclick = function () {
    alert(times + " adds up to " + getTotal(times));
};
```

```html
<button id="add">add</button>
<button id="startsequence">total</button>
```

`Array.reduce` is just a fancier version of your for loop. You can read the docs [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce).

Comment: Awesome, thanks! I'm pretty new to this (clearly). I thought my total var would "update" based on the events.

Comment: @ESH note: if you're only ever going to populate the array with `1`s, then you can just use `times.length` instead of `getTotal(times)`.

Answer (score 0):

When your count is executed there is nothing in the array.

You should execute your count in the click handler of your `total` button

See updated [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/6sp29efd/2/)

By the way, you could do your computation in a more sexy way with **reduce** :

```
document.getElementById("startsequence").onclick = function () {
    var total = times.reduce(function (a, b) {
        return a + b;
    });
    alert(times + " adds up to " + total);
};
```

Answer (score 0):

It's because your for loop that count the elements in the array is executed only at the beginning of your program, when the "times" array is empty.

You have to calculate the length of "times" array  when you actually request the total count clicking "start sequence" element on your DOM.

```
var times = [];

function calcTotal () {
   var total = 0;

   for (var i = 0; i < times.length; i++) {
    total += +times[i];
   }

   return total;
}


document.getElementById("add").onclick = function () {
    times.push(1);
};

document.getElementById("startsequence").onclick = function () {
    alert(times + " adds up to " + calcTotal());
};
```

I've wrapped the for loop inside a function that is called when you request the total. This way you can calculate the length of the array exactly when you need it.

https://jsfiddle.net/ncqyLpr1/

Answer (score 0):

You calculate total before any elements were created. times is empty, has 0 elements, its length is 0. You initialize i with 0, which is already not smaller than times.length and the value of total remains 0. You need to do something like this:

```
var times = [];

var total = 0;

document.getElementById("add").onclick = function () {
    times.push(1);
};

document.getElementById("total").onclick = function () {
    total = 0;
    for (var i = 0; i < times.length; i++) {
        total += +times[i];
    }
    alert(times + " adds up to " + total);
};
```